# Aliasing routes in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following routes

```
resources :pages do
    resources :sections
end
```

I get routes that look like this:

```
/pages  = #index
/pages/:id = #show
/pages/:id/edit = #edit
...etc
```

How can I go about making it so that the url for the #show action of the pages controller looks like '/:id', without the '/pages/' prefix? should I exclude #show from resources :page & create a get route + alias for it separately? or is there a way to do it from inside the resources :page block? Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:**

Changed it to:

```
resources :pages, except: [:show] do
  resources :sections
end

get '/:id', to: 'pages#show'
```

& rerouting non-existing :ids' to 404 for now, let me know if there's a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get '/:id', to: 'pages#show', as: 'page'
```

Make sure this is at the bottom of your `routes.rb` file, otherwise it is going to hijack requests to other routes.

This also gives you `page_url` and `page_path` helper methods. But to use them you must exclude `show` action from previous routes.

```
resources :pages, except: [:show]
```

Comment: Note that, if you're going to do this, you should remove the `show` action from `resources :pages` with `resources :pages, except: 'show'`